# Access home web services remotely with DDNS and NAT forwarding

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat, ddns

I have a local server running a couple of web service on different ports. The server is connected to a router so I can access these if I am on the same LAN.

- The server has a static local ip: `192.169.1.113`
- My web service is accessed locally with `192.168.1.113:8054`
- ISP does not give static IP so DDNS is setup: `example.tplinkdns.com`

When I run `ping example.tplinkdns.com` from a terminal, I see that this points to my router's public ip. Meaning DDNS is working.

The router also has a NAT port forwarding functionality. So I would like to access my services through the DDNS domain. With the above example something like:

```
http://example.tplinkdns.com:8054
```

**Is this possible with NAT port forwarding?**

**If yes,** how would this be setup since the DDNS does not automatically point to `192.168.1.113`. From NAT setup, all I can do is point the external port of 8054 to point to `192.168.1.113:8054`

**If no**, why? and is there a way to have this kind of setup?

Comment: What are the first two parts of you public IP address?

Comment: @DavidPostill why does that matter?

Comment: Your ISP maybe using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks. Assuming this is not the case, will the above setup work?

Comment: If your router has port forwarding, then this should be fairly easy. Did you try it, and if so, what were the problems?

Comment: Note that unless you have a enterprise or fairly sophisticated router, you won't be able to use the public IP to access services while you are inside your own network. it will only work from systems outside your network. the reason is that a feature called "NAT Hairpinning" is required to make that work, and most consumer grade routers do not support it. in those cases I suggest you use an internal DNS server to host a zone for your internal LAN, with the same name as the zone you host on public DDNS. that way for www.x.y.z, an external gets 1.2.3.4, and an internal gets 192.168.x.y.